# Are acyl chlorides acidic?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Are acyl chlorides such as $\ce{CH3COCl}$
 acidic in water or any other solvent?

Are they in any context referred to as acid chlorides? Or is that just a mistake?

Comment: Acyl chlorides don't even **exist** in water. They would hydrolyze instantly and produce acids.

Comment: Of course. I forgot. So is that why they are considered acidic? Beacause they produce carboxyllic acids in reaction with water.

Comment: @IvanNeretin They don't hydrolyze _that_ fast. You can do kinetics at zero degrees C: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo9609844?journalCode=joceah